# ow to make a collapsible/expandable list with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make a list collapsible that does not have any type of segmentation besides its class?

a list like this:

```
<ol class="lessons">
    <li class="lesson-item">
        <div class="item-list-section-heading"> Title 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 1
    </li>
    <li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 2
    </li>
    <li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 3
    </li>
    <li class="lesson-item">
        <div class="item-list-section-heading"> Title 2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 4
    </li>
    <li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 5
    </li>
    <li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 6
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/F99G7rk.png) and when you click text will appear?

Comment: So you want each of the **item-list-section-heading** to show the items below it?

Comment: You could develop this yourself, though it's a standard component in Bootstrap and many other libraries.  See:  [Bootstrap Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-items)

Comment: yes just something like that would be great, but I can't modify the html, could I add css or javascript code and achieve the same? @Ethan

Comment: @Talked “_but I can't modify the html_”: Do you mean not at all? Or is it ok for the JS to modify the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the HTML in any way, I'm not sure that it'll be possible to get the result that you want.

If you can use JavaScript to modify the markup, then below is a technique for doing so. Each list will be replaced with a [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) element, and each group of [list items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) under the list's headings will become a unique list within a [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) element.

After reorganization, the markup for the node that replaces the original list ends up looking like this:

```html
<section>
  <details>
    <summary><div class="item-list-section-heading"> Title 1</div></summary>
    <ol start="1">
      <li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 1
      </li><li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 2
      </li><li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 3
      </li>
    </ol>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary><div class="item-list-section-heading"> Title 2</div></summary>
    <ol start="4">
      <li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 4
      </li><li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 5
      </li><li class="lesson-item">
        subTitle 6
      </li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</section>
```

> The [`start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#attr-start) attribute on [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) elements controls the starting index of its child list items.

```js
function createDetailsList (summaryChild, startIndex) {
  const summary = document.createElement('summary');
  summary.appendChild(summaryChild);

  const ol = document.createElement('ol');
  ol.start = startIndex;

  const details = document.createElement('details');
  details.appendChild(summary);
  details.appendChild(ol);

  return {details, ol};
}

function reorganizeLessons (ol) {
  const section = document.createElement('section');
  let count = 1;
  let currentList;

  for (const li of ol.querySelectorAll(':scope > li.lesson-item')) {
    const sectionHeadingDiv =
      li.querySelector(':scope > div.item-list-section-heading');

    if (sectionHeadingDiv) {
      const result = createDetailsList(sectionHeadingDiv, count);
      currentList = result.ol;
      section.appendChild(result.details);
      continue;
    }

    if (!currentList) {
      throw new Error('Encountered child list item without a heading');
    }

    currentList.appendChild(li);
    count += 1;
  }

  ol.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', section);
  ol.remove();
}

function reorganizeLists () {
  for (const ol of document.querySelectorAll('ol.lessons')) {
    reorganizeLessons(ol);
  }
}

function main () {
  const btn = document.querySelector('button.reorganize');

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    reorganizeLists();
    btn.remove();
  }, {once: true});
}

main();
```

```css
.item-list-section-heading { display: inline; }
```

```html
<ol class="lessons">
  <li class="lesson-item">
    <div class="item-list-section-heading"> Title 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="lesson-item">
    subTitle 1
  </li>
  <li class="lesson-item">
    subTitle 2
  </li>
  <li class="lesson-item">
    subTitle 3
  </li>
  <li class="lesson-item">
    <div class="item-list-section-heading"> Title 2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="lesson-item">
    subTitle 4
  </li>
  <li class="lesson-item">
    subTitle 5
  </li>
  <li class="lesson-item">
    subTitle 6
  </li>
</ol>

<button class="reorganize">Reorganize</button>
```